# Not able to show message when user logged in from other device

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have done the functionality of when user is logged in from one device. Then if he logged in from other device then he will be logged out and redirect to login page.

**I have done this functionality through a session. when user logged in, I save a value in database and every time he go to other page I match the values (saved in database and in session both) if they don't match (if user is logged in from other device the value in database will be updated so will not match with the session value ) I redirect user to login page**

**the problem is I m not able to show message (simple message or popup ) when user go to login page.**

kindly tell me how can I show message ?

or tell me if this functionality I have done is not good or I have to use some other method through javascript or any other resource

I want to show message before redirect to login page like when user logged in from other device he showed a message on previous device that u're logged in from other device is that you ? if Yes keep him logged in if No then logged out and redirect to login page.

**based on the functionality i mentioned in my question. is the above functionality can be done ?**

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to the login page, just add a parameter : `/Account/Login?loggedOnOtherDevice=true`

And on the login page, you can check the parameter :

```
public ActionResult Login(bool? loggedOnOtherDevice){
    if (loggedOnOtherDevice.GetValueOrDefault()){
        // Here, add code or update your model to display the message
    }


    return View();
}
```